# Application Request Routing doesn't route to same machine

Tags: routes, iis-7.5, arr, iis-arr

I have setup an ARR in my IIS server. My requirement is I have to route a request to this ARR server to one of my application which is hosted in local IIS(ARR server itself). Is it possible?

ie. Suppose in my ARR server has Application1. Then I have to do the following

Broswer -> ARR (iis server) -> Application1(which is itself in ARR server).

If possible how can implement such a setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

You need, at least, 2 sites to implement this. One will get the requests and route them to ARR via a Rewrite Rule, the other one will be the node behind ARR.

For example, considering your domain name is "example.com":

```
IIS
  - Site 1 (binding: http://example.com:80)
  - Site 2 (binding: http://127.0.0.1:22001)

Rewrite Rule
  - Match All
    - {HTTP_HOST} matches example.com
    - {SERVER_PORT} does not match 22001
 - Action: Route to Farm
```

This is a good starting point to do zero-downtime deployment. If you want to know more check this repo on GitHub: https://github.com/yosoyadri/IIS-ARR-Zero-Downtime

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like it being on the same port, you can also have it go to a different IP instead.